# How can LDAP-based SSO between .Net and PHP systems be done?

Tags: .net, ldap, sitecore, single-sign-on, lamp

I've been working with LAMP systems so I am relatively ignorant about MS technologies. We have a customer with an existing website powered by a .Net CMS called sitecore. They want to use one of our products which is another web system powered by LAMP technologies. For simplicity let's say that if you type in site.com, you'll end up on sitecore section of the website and if you type in app.site.com, you'll get to our LAMP app.

Our goal is to integrate the two systems. So the main .Net website will have "sign in" form and whenever that one is filled in, the user should be signed in both .Net system and our LAMP system. We obviously have full control over our LAMP system and we can code any handlers there however we don't have much control over the .Net system. I've done some research and LDAP seems to be the standard way people employ to implement SSO in such cases but I am still trying to figure out how it works. My current understanding is that LDAP is something like an external database and once .Net system is configured to work with it (sitecore does provide such integration), login+pass entered in the sign in form, will be getting validated against LDAP. What is not clear to me is how our LAMP system will get notified whenever user is signed in? So I am basically struggling to understand the general flow of such integration: user goes to .Net website, enters login+pass, gets authenticated, .Net website stores that in cookie/session (or whatever is employed for these purposes in such systems) and then our LAMP system somehow needs to do the same but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP is simply a storage solution for a lot of things. You can store passwords in there as well and ask the LDAP whether a given password is ok for a given user. So you can use LDAP for authentication. And because a lot of systems can use one LDAP you can build a "one password for all" solution around an LDAP.

To use real SSO as you specified it, there is a little more work to be done, as generation of tokens and so forth is far beyond the scope of LDAP.

There is a solution called **KERBEROS** out there for SSO which can be based on LDAP-authentication. It's the solution used by Microsofts ActiveDirectory or Apples OpenDirectory and others. I believe .Net can use it and as far as I know there are ways to "kerberize" apaches httpd to use real SSO with it.

For more information have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter what the systems are based on. I think you just need to get a good grasp of how single sign on actually works and then you'll see it can work with anything.

I will give an explanation, in very basic terms, of how single sign-on works. In this example, we have the following sites:

- Site-A = Sitecore Site
- Site-B = LAMP Site

The following flow implements single sign-on:

1. User visits Site-A and logs in
2. Site-A generates a security token (**(*)** - see below) and stores it in the database
   (we call it SQL)
3. Site-A sets a cookie that indicates user is logged in
4. Site-A redirects user to Site-B and passes along the username, the security
   token and a return URL (the location to go to after login)
5. Site-B received the data, takes the username, generates the token
   by itself and it compares it with the token that was passed through
6. If the tokens match, this means the user may be authenticated, Site-B sets
   a cookie that indicates the user is logged in
7. Site-B redirects to the return URL
8. The user is now logged in on both Site-A and Site-B

**(*)** -- The security token can be generated using something like a username + a salt (let's say, as secret string value, that both parties know) the concatenation of those two is encrypted using MD5.
So let's say the username is "joe" and the salt is "supersecret", the concatenation is "joesupersecret" and that results in an MD5 hash.

Please note that this is just a very basic example of how it can work. In reality, there are many variations to this implementation, but it all comes down to the same basics.

As you see, it doesn't matter if you are using .NET or PHP systems of if they authenticate with LDAP or something else; each system handles their own method of authentication.

Comment: This would work but isn't it more like a custom SSO implementation? When researching the topic, I got an impression that MS offers some built in SSO mechanism called LDAP SSO. It sounds like a variation of Apache's HTTP authentication - it's done by server and then the server somehow can notify other servers about the success and make $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] variable available for use. Something like this http://drupal.org/node/1371478 I just can't still understand how other server securely receives information about authentication success.